# Locate react elements inside shadowroot using typescript and Protractor [

Tags: reactjs, typescript, protractor

Im trying to locate elements that are inside 9-11 shadow root. Regular locators such as xpath,css,id are not able to locate. I was able to locate element using JavascriptExecutor() in java. But the process is very tedious. Also im  working on protractor framework with typescript.
I need to locate the element highlighted.

Any help is much appreciated!![enter image description here][1]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using custom javascript to find your elements, I would recommend the 'by.react' component, this makes react selection so much easier.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/protractor-react-selector

```
// with only component. If you don't provide any root element, it assume that root is set to '#root'
const myElement = element(by.react('MyComponent'));

// to fetch all elements matched with component, props and state, you can use protractor native 'all' method
const myElement = element.all(by.react('MyComponent'));
```

Let me know if this helps you :)

Comment: Thanks for the info. However, im getting TypeError: protractor_1.by.react is not a function
What is the import statement in typescript?

Comment: you need to install the library. `npm i -D protractor-react-selector`. Follow the blog: https://medium.com/@abhinabaghosh.1994/test-your-react-app-efficiently-with-protractor-b8406db9148f